# Was the Nitpicker's Guide for Deep Space Nine ever completed?

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Late to the party, but as part of re-watching DS9, I picked up a used copy of [*The Nitpicker's Guide for Deep Space 9 Trekkers*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Nitpicker%27s_Guide_for_Deep_Space_Nine_Trekkers). Sadly, it only covers the first four seasons.

Was the remainder of the show ever covered by this author?

Some research explained the book series stopped for legal reasons, but there is a website, [www.nitcentral.com](http://www.nitcentral.com).  However, I was unable to figure out the site navigation, and kept receiving "500 Internal Server Errors" as well.  If this material exists, and anyone knows how to find it, I'd appreciate a pointer to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The books were discontinued by the author's publisher, Dell Books following the [Toho Vs. Morrow](https://h2o.law.harvard.edu/cases/4817) legal ruling and a [dramatic rise in cease-and-desist letters sent by Paramount](https://www.wired.com/1996/12/paramount-locks-phasers-on-trek-fan-sites/)

Farrand seems to have continued to publish nitpicker books, but only with the *explicit consent* of the various studios involved. Presumably Paramount declined to give that consent, hence why the books remain incomplete.

---

You can read the author's statement [here](http://www.nitcentral.com/askchief/ac980515.htm#bullies) in full.

> My current writing career ended sometime around noon last Monday when
> my agent Steve Ettlinger called. (Quite a way to start the week, eh?)
>
> ...
>
> Here's the facts as I know them. Apparently, there was an unauthorized
> movie guide for Godzilla that was due to be released in conjunction
> with the new movie. In mid-April, the copyright and trademark owners
> of Godzilla won an injunction against the publisher of the
> unauthorized guide and stopped it's release.
>
> Unfortunately, the judgment in the case was written quite broadly.
>
> At the same time, Paramount has been stomping through the unauthorized
> publishing niche--as they did on the web several months back--firing
> off letters to anyone and everyone that they feel might be infringing
> on their copyrights. A few weeks ago, I spoke with a fellow author
> whose publisher had yanked his DS9 trivia book after he had already
> turned in the manuscript.
>
> ...
>
> **Dell has canceled the Star Wars Nitpicker's Guide and has stated that
> it has no interest in publishing any other Nitpicker's Guides.**
>
> However, as far as I know, Dell will continue to sell the current
> spate of Guide. But . . . my relationship with them has ended.
>
> And . . . it seems unlikely that another publisher would be willing to
> take on the risk--given the atmosphere of the market and other current
> lawsuits.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no further material. Nitcentral lists 5 books of Phil Farrand: TNG part 1 (1993), TOS (1994), TNG part 2 (1995), DS9 (1996) and X-philes (1997). And the 1996 book for DS9 is the one you mentioned, covering seasons 1 to 4.